# Memory bottleneck with autoregressive transformer decoding

Tags: pytorch, transformer-model

I am trying to train a transformer model for sequence modeling. Below is a standalone example:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

criterion = nn.MSELoss()

decoder_layer = nn.TransformerDecoderLayer(d_model=512, nhead=8)
transformer_decoder = nn.TransformerDecoder(decoder_layer, num_layers=12)
memory = torch.rand(10, 32, 512)
y = torch.rand(20, 32, 512)

start_token = torch.ones((1,32,512))
tgt_input = torch.cat((start_token,y[:-1,:]),axis=0)

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(transformer_decoder.parameters())

###################Teacher forced
while(True):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    out = transformer_decoder(tgt_input, memory, nn.Transformer.generate_square_subsequent_mask(20,20))

    loss = criterion(out,y)
    print("loss: ", loss.item())
    
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

For a 12 layer decoder, the model works fine on a personal machine with 8GB memory. The model is autoregressive and works with shifted targets. Given we provide targets above, I refer to this setting as "teacher forced".

However, at inference stage, we will not have targets fed as above, and one would need to condition on targets generated on the go. This setting is as follows:

```
###################Non Teacher forced
while(True):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    predictions = torch.ones((1,32,512))
    for i in range(1,21):
        predictions = torch.cat((predictions, transformer_decoder(tgt_input[:i], memory, nn.Transformer.generate_square_subsequent_mask(i,i))[-1].unsqueeze(0)),axis=0)
        print("i: ", i, "predictions.shape: ", predictions.shape)
        
    loss = criterion(predictions[1:],y)
    print("loss: ", loss.item())
    
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

I wish to train the model with a hybrid training strategy with, without teacher forcing. However, the non-teacher forced strategy causes out-of-memory exception and doesn't work. For final inference (testing), usually, `with torch.no_grad()` it can work, but not in training. Can anyone explain as to why this causes memory bottlenecks exactly?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the rolling of the computational graph. For the teacher forced model, gradients are not propagated after the true values. However, for non-teacher forced model they backpropagate making the accumulation of gradients (similar to RNN).

Answer (score 0):

- You can try inspecting the caption generator part of the model and
  try using `torch.no_grad()` in some parts of the code where the
  backdrop is not needed. In this way, you can save some memory.
- Additionally, you can try reducing the maximum sequence length
  optimally (I tried by trial and error).

I faced quite a similar issue and following the steps above I managed to increase the batch size to some extent.